# PHP+Mysql left join and like

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want left join to other table and like

> My code :

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM `offer` 
    LEFT JOIN `category` ON (category.id=offer.brand OR category.id=offer.model) 
    WHERE offer.active='1' AND `finish`='0' AND 
         (category.title LIKE '%2013%' OR category.title_en LIKE '%2013%' OR
          offer.year LIKE '%2013%') 
GROUP BY offer.id 
ORDER BY `last_update` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

> Offer table :

```
id     year     brand      model
------------------------------------
1      1390     1          2
2      2050     2          3
3      2010     1          4
4      2200     4          1
```

> Category Table

```
id     title     title_en
------------------------------------
1      kia       kia_url
2      optima    optima_url
3      name      name_url
4      benz      benz_url
```

After run my code and LIKE BENZ, i want return ID 4 from OFFER table

Comment: And the problem  is ?

Comment: Please let us know what is expected and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want return row from OFFER table where like from CATEGORY.TITLE

Comment: Post your database schema and some data if possible

Comment: check for condition ... finish = ''0' ... seems strange .

Comment: Check again please

Comment: Replace your WHERE with AND

Comment: @Mihai can you explain more ?

Comment: your table does not have `finish` column. and even if it runs successfully it might result in ambiguous column finish error. also this column `last_update` does not appear to be in db

Comment: apart from using non-existing columns and potentialy ambiguous columns, if the sample rows shown here are all of the records you actually have, then `category.title LIKE '%2013%' OR category.title_en LIKE '%2013%'` has no matching rows anyway (no `title` or `title_en` column has "2013" in it)